# Extending Optional for all Types except one

Tags: swift, option-type

In the interest of efficient coding, I was wondering if there is a way to write an extension on `Optional` for all wrapper types With a declared exception.

In this particular instance, that would be `String`.

My desired use-case would be as follows:

```
extension Optional where Wrapped != String {
    var asString: String? { return self as? String }
}
```

I'm getting a whole bunch of compilation errors here, where of course this is not possible.
I want to be able to do this so that I don't see the `asString` property on `String?` objects, as there is some redundancy there, of course.

---

<sup>*Note: this should be able to be applied to any valid type that `Wrapped` can take.*</sup>

Comment: No, it is impossible. It would be nightmare to implement such feature in the language.

Comment: I wonder how it would be better to write `variable.asString` instead of `variable as?  String`. Also, if you could implement such an extension, it would always return `nil` because `self` would never be a `String`.

Comment: @Sulthan that is.. an insight I’d clearly overlooked! Cheers

Answer (score 0):

```
extension Optional {
    var asString: String? {
        guard let unwrapped = self else {
            return nil
        }
        return "\(unwrapped)"
    }
}
```

This solution is only allowed by the language

You can't exclude some classes or protocols in `where` block.

Example,

```
let some: Range? = 0..<1
some.asString
```

> "0..<1"

Comment: This is a more difficult way to write `optionalVariable.map { "\($0)" }`. It's not really "asString" as defined by OP but rather `toString` because it does a data conversion.